# Error creating an Apache Apollo broker

Tags: apache, activemq-classic, messagebroker, broker, apollo

I downloaded and unzipped the Apache Apollo distribution as [described in their site](https://activemq.apache.org/apollo/documentation/getting-started.html).

```
~/Developer/Web/MQTT/apache-apollo-1.7.1/bin/apollo create mybroker
```

I got teh below output in the Terminal.

> Creating apollo instance at: mybroker
>
> ERROR: mybroker/etc/log4j.properties (No such file or directory)

That command is supposed to create the `etc` sub directory among others.

Any idea why this error is occurring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I resolved it. I installed Apollo via Homebrew successfully. Then I cd'ed to `/var/lib` and ran the following command. This time with `sudo`.

```
sudo apollo create mybroker
```

It created the broker successfully. Then I ran the below command to run it. Again with `sudo`.

```
sudo mybroker/bin/apollo-broker run
```

Which started the broker and I could login via the web dashboard at http://127.0.0.1:61680/ too.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ubuntu 16.0.4. And I encountered the same problem. I resolved by this:
use "sudo apollo create......"
it seems because the apollo didn't have authorities to create document in /etc/